# Why the accuracy and loss number is different compared with the train phase if I load a trained model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Normally I would use the code `torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'test.pth')` to save the best model based on the performance of the validation set.

In the training phase, I print the **loss** and **Accuracy** in the last epoch and I got **Loss:0.38703016219139097** and **Accutacy:86.9**.

However, When I load the model which I just got from the training phase to print the **loss** and **Accuracy**, I would get the same **Accuracy** and **different loss:  0.38702996191978456**.

Why would that happen? I try different datasets and neural networks, but get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, at the end of each epoch, you print the training accuracy/loss, and also save the model if it beats the current best model on the validation set. Is that it?

Because if my understanding of the situation is correct, then it is perfectly normal. Your "best" model in regards of the TRAINING accuracy/loss is under no obligation to also be the best in regards of the VALIDATION accuracy/loss. (One of the best examples of this is the overfitting phenomenon)

Comment: I would print **train loss**, **train acc**, **val loss**, **val acc**, **test loss**, **test acc** each time. But the program would only save the model based on the performance of the **val acc**. 

According to my code, at the end of the training, it would generate a new neural network (Something like `model = models.resnet18(pretrained=False)`) to load the best model saved by training phase to print the **test loss** and **test acc**. And I got **Loss:0.38703016219139097**

But if I write a new code to load the model and the same test set, I would get a different **0.38702996191978456**

Comment: So you train your model, keep the "validation-best" out of all the epochs, load it into a new model, print the **test acc** and the **test loss**. Then you re-load this same model into another new one, and the **test acc**/**test loss** isn't the same anymore?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. But now I found out the BATCH SIZE is the problem. If I use the same BATCH SIZE, I can get absolutely the same result. But now I am thinking about why the BACTH SIZE would influence the loss number in the testing phase while it won't influence the accuracy number.

Comment: Because if you don't test on the same (exactly same) datasets, you won't get the same results. Each datapoint introduces error to some extent, and it is that error you measure with loss or accuracy. If you make the average of grades of 20 students in a class, or only a random 10 of them, you aren't likely to find the same value. The same mechanism is at play here.

Comment: Also the **test** error is but an estimation of the **true** error (would be obtained if the model was tested on the whole underlying distribution). As it is an estimation, it is not the same if you don't have the same data. To further use the analogy, the **test** error would be the average grade of 20 students out of the whole class (which may give you a good estimation or not, depending on the size of the class), while the **true** error would be the average of the grades of **all** students.